# PHP call to PayPal RESTFUL API using Curl returns 'unauthorized'

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

I am using the PayPal RESTful API and am able to create transactions from the command line using curl, but have not been able to get this to work using PHP, and have some general questions about the API I have not found answers to in the documentation.  My hope is to direct the user to PayPal to log in and process the payment, sending them to the site with a transaction amount based on form input from my site.  Using curl from the command line, I can successfully get a PayPal Session token using:

```
    curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token   -H "Accept: application/json"   -H "Accept-Language: en_US"   -u "[client id]:[secret]"   -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

This returns a response with an access token as expected.  In PHP, I am making the same curl request and getting the same results, so there are no problems with this step.

Once I have the token, I am able to use it to make a purchase via curl on the command line with the following code:

```
    curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer [token]' -d '{
    "redirect_urls":{
    "return_url":"http://ruxed.com/thank-you/",
    "cancel_url":"http://ruxed.com/make-a-payment/"
    },
    "payer":{
    "payment_method":"paypal"
    },
    "transactions":[
    {
    "amount":{
    "total":"10.00",
    "currency":"USD"
    }
    }
    ]
    }'
```

This works well from curl an the command line, in that I get a response indicating that the payment succeed, and I can then log into my PayPal Developer dashboard and see the record logged.  I am confused by this, however, as I have not provided any account from which this payment should be coming from-- I have not provided a PayPal user name or any other information, so how does PayPal know where to take these funds from?

From PHP, I am making the same curl call, but am getting a '401 unauthorized' response.  Here is the code for the curl: (code formatting on stackoverflow crapped out for me here and would not let me submit the question with code wrappers, so no code wrappers for you).

```
$headers = array( # BUILD HEADERS FOR CURL
sprintf('Authorization: Bearer %s', $_POST['token']),
'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$data = array( # BUILD DATA FOR CURL
'intent' => 'sale',
"redirect_urls" => array(
"return_url" => "http://ruxed.com/thank-you/",
"cancel_url" => "http://ruxed.com/make-a-payment/"
),
"payer" => array( "payment_method" => "paypal" ),
"transactions" => array(
array(
"amount" => array(
"total" => $_POST['actual_payment'],
"currency" => "USD"
)
)
)
);
$curl = curl_init( "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment" ); // INIT CURL
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true ); 
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers ); // SET HEADERS
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); 
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $data ) ); // SET POST DATA
$result = curl_exec( $curl ); # ROCK THE CURL
if( empty( $result ) ) die( curl_error( $curl ) ); # IF RESPONSE IS EMPTY, THERE WAS AN ERROR
curl_close( $curl ); # CLOSE THE CURL
```

My hope is that the above code will direct the user to PayPal to log in with their account and process the payment for the amount that is being passed, as I am not requesting their PayPal login credentials on my site.  What is wrong with my PHP curl request that it is unauthorized, and am I approaching this the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

@user2252436

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

I think that CURLOPT_HEADER requires an int or bool, either 1 or TRUE to send headers.

I do believe CURLOP_HTTPHEADER is what you want, you can pass an array directly to it without encoding to a query string.

e.g.

```
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlHeaders);
```